# Why is Netbeans not communicating with my android emulator devices?

Tags: android, netbeans, android-emulator, adb

At the moment, I have Netbeans 8.0.2 installed on my machine. Previously, I had a version of 7.X, I can't remember the exact version. The last time I remember, my Netbeans was able to communicate with the emulator without a problem, I could run and test applications on them. Then I installed Android Studio to get a feel of how it works. I really didn't like it, thus uninstalled it. Then my problems began. My Netbeans can neither communicate with the Emulator devices nor with actual physical devices when trying to test my apps. I have tried manually killing and restarting the ADB server, re-installing old Netbeans versions, and even reinstalling the old Android SDK, but nothing is working. Netbeans still cannot communicate with other emulators or physical devices. When the Android emulator is running, a sample of the Netbeans log says:

```
...//other output
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.android.core.ddm.AndroidDebugBridgeFactory]: 
W PropertyFetcher AdbCommandRejectedException getting properties for 
device emulator-5554: device offline

INFO [org.nyerel.nbandroid.logcat.LogReader]: searching for device with 
sn: emulator-5554

INFO [org.nyerel.nbandroid.logcat.LogReader]: device: emulator-5554

INFO [org.nyerel.nbandroid.logcat.LogReader]: searching for device with 
sn: emulator-5554

INFO [org.nyerel.nbandroid.logcat.LogReader]: device: emulator-5554
...//keeps repeating last two statements
```

Yet the emulator is running. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check your NetBeans 8.0.2 Plugins. 
Tools->Plugins
You may have to activate/reactivate your Git plugin. 
Click on installed tab and make sure Git is activated. If not, select it and click on activate. 
I had a similar problem with the Cordova project missing when I upgraded to 8.0.2. I had to reactivate my Cordova Support plugin.

Comment: Git plugin is running, and am curious as to how it affects communications between the emulator and Netbeans